# setuid has same effect as sudo?

Tags: permissions, sudo, setuid

does setting uid has the same effect that sudo has?
What happens if setuid'ed executable open whoami with popen? Do I get 'root'?

Comment: Wait, _`manatails`_? Is that you, the Pokémon gifter?

Answer (score 1):

The `sudo` command affects the credentials of the current user to launching a given process.  The `setuid` command affects the credentials of any user launching a given process.

Comment: Then I will get 'root' as output if my executable calls whoami?